# Expanding snippet in line using neosnippet

Tags: snippets

I'm using [neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim) to define and expand my snippets.

I have the following snippet defined for javascript development

```
snippet fn
abbr () => {}
    (${1}) => {${2}}
```

I can insert this snippet when starting to type on a new line using `C-k`. However I often find myself in the position where i wish to insert in in an existing line

```
let something = fn
test.then(fn)
```

when I'm after `fn` on either of these lines I would like to expand the snippet. Can this be achieved using neosnippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
snippet fn
option word
abbr () => {}
    (${1}) => {${2}}
```

You can find the necessary information if you read `:h neosnippet-snippet-syntax`, in particular the help under the snippet keyword `option`:

```
- options [options] (Optional)

    Options influence the snippet behavior. The possible values are:

    + word  This snippet expands by a word boundary.
        Note: To complete the trigger with neosnippet, it must be a
        word character (digits, alphabetical characters or "_").

    snippet     date
    options     word
        `strftime("%d %b %Y")`
```

The help text continuous with more help text on more options, but `word` is the relevant option here.